# Withing script X getting the PID of the process which feeds the stdin

Tags: bash, pid

I want to execute **Program_A**, and have it output examined by **Program_B**. e.g.

```
$ Program_A | Program_B
```

Within **Program_B**, I would like to be able to terminate **Program_A** if a certain condition matched.

I am looking for a way to do this in **BASH** (have a solution in python with popen).

Also, `pidof Program_A` and alike are not a good solution since there can be many instances of it and only a particular one shall be terminated.

Comment: Can you get the process id of Program_A in the Program_A itself and print that as the first line and other outputs to Program_B. If you do this then you can kill the Program_A with kill call from Program_B

Comment: @Raghuram rewrite this comment as an answer so I can accept it

Comment: added the comment as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the process id of Program_A in the Program_A itself and print that as the first line and other outputs to Program_B. If you do this then you can kill the Program_A with kill call from Program_B

Answer (score 0):

In Program_B you could `close()` stdin when you detect the closing condition. It will cause Program_A to receive error upon `write()` and possibly terminate.

Now, the Program_A may choose to ignore those errors (I don't know if it's your own application or a pre-compiled tool) and here comes the funny part. In Program_B you can examine where does your stdin come from:

```
my_input=`readlink /proc/$$/fd/0`
```

then, if it's a something like "pipe:[134414]", find any other process whose stdout equals

```
case "$my_input" in
  pipe:*)
    for p in /proc/[0-9]*
    do
      if [ "$my_input" = "`readlink $p/fd/1`" ]
      then
        bad_guy=`sed -e 's:.*/::' <<< "$p"`
        echo "Would you please finish, Mr. $bad_guy ?!"
        kill $bad_guy
        break
      fi
    done
    ;;
  *)
    echo "We're good";;
esac
```